# Set up load event on windows form tab

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, load

I am currently working in vb.net with windows form applications. I am using a multi-tab windows form where I want a data grid view to be loaded with information from an sql table as soon as the form opens. However, I can not find an event that uses the load feature coupled with the tab. Is there a way to hard code this?

```
...
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridLine2.CellContentClick

        Try
            Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                conn1.Open()
                Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM Production.dbo.tblOrdered", conn1)

                    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
                    da.SelectCommand = comm1
                    da.Fill(dt)
                    'select customerName as customer, contactname as contact person
                    'from cusomters;
                End Using
                conn1.Close()
            End Using

            DataGridLine2.DataSource = dt

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Unable to make SQL Connection, please contact an engineer!")
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what do you mean by Form Load "coupled" with a tab?  One is an event, one is a UI object. Is the DGV on a tab?  Does each tab have a DGV? What part of the problem does that code illustrate?

Comment: When i say form load coupled with a tab I mean as soon as i open this form with a button from a previous form, I want that table to be loaded into the tab. Each tab in the windows form will have a DGV and I want every tab to automatically load the table in it. This code is what I have set up within the tab right now.

Comment: that code appears to be a DGV cell click event - way downstream from form load.  If you are loading data to a DGV in form load, whats the problem?  If nothing is showing up, show the code to populate one Tabbed DGV from your form load.

Comment: Nvm guys i answered it myself, unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to answer my own question. I set up the code to run in the load event and id did not work, I moved the code to the tab and it still did not work. When I moved my code back to the load event it worked out. You can load a DGV into a tab from the load event. It must have been something else wrong with my initial load code that got worked out. Thanks guys!

Comment: On the form load, you could call a function that will populate the grids.

Comment: Yea i got it lotus, thanks though, if someone answers the question with "you can use the load event for a DGV in a tab on a windows form." I will give them a check mark to close this question.